# date.toLocaleDateString is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, date, botframework

Have simple function which returns an error:

> ERROR: date.toLocaleDateString is not a function

```
TypeError: date.toLocaleDateString is not a function
    at FormatTime (../Src/rootdialog.js:87:58)
```

Function definition:

```
function FormatTime(time, prefix = "") {
    var date = Date.parse(time);
    return ((typeof time != "undefined") ? prefix + date.toLocaleDateString()  : "");
}
```

Function receives `Date` object as input however even explicit conversion to `Date` with `Date.parse()` does not help. Using Node.js 8.x. Any solution?

> **P.S.** Issue was caused by [BotBuilder architecture](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3338).

Comment: `Date.parse` returns a number. You are looking for `new Date`. Or, if `time` already is a Date instance, just use `time.toLocaleDateString()`!

Comment: What is the value of *time*?

Comment: @Bergi thanks, this works. Strange when values was inside function - their was `Date` type with `Date()` constructor, outside - become strings: probably bot framework on waterfall flow functions assignment loses type and need to convert explicitly. You may move Your comment to answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) returns a number. You are looking for [`new Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Or, if `time` already is a Date instance, just use `time.toLocaleDateString()` (and make sure it really is in every call to the function)!

```
function formatTime(time, prefix = "") {
    return typeof time == "object" ? prefix + time.toLocaleDateString() : "";
}
```

Answer (score 48):

You can use

```
new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Got this error in a React app, solved it like this:

```
{ (item.created instanceof Date) ? item.created.toLocaleDateString() : new Date(item.created).toLocaleDateString() }
```

Comment: You can directly use `new Date(date).toLocaleDateString();`, On your code a if condition will take time to excecute.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely getting `NaN` as the result of your `Date.parse(time)` call.
Check the MDN article on [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for the types of input strings it accepts if you think your time argument should be valid.

You may want to modify your return statement so it's checking for failed parses instead of just undefined, e.g.:

```
function FormatTime(time, prefix = "") {
    var date = Date.parse(time); // returns NaN if it can't parse
    return Number.isNaN(date) ? "" : prefix + date.toLocaleDateString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error by using the code below;

Instead of `date.toLocaleDateString`, use `toLocaleString`

// month, day, year respectively

```
const month = props.date.toLocaleString('en-US', {month:'long'});
const day = props.date.toLocaleString('en-US', {day:'2-digit'});
const year = props.date.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score -4):

```
 function(ng-model_Name,ng-model_Name) {
     var fromdate = new Date($scope.ng-model_Name.from.toLocaleDateString());
     var todate = new Date($scope.ng-model_Name.to.toLocaleDateString());
     return $scope.variable= asign; 
 }
```

Comment: Please elaborate *how* and *why* this solves the issue.